# Подъем функции в ES6

Tags: javascript

Почему объявление функции поднимается в начало блока, а ее идентификатор доступен аж в начале сценария с не определенным значением (undefined) ?

```
<script>

console.log(foo); // undefined

if(true) {

  console.log(foo()); // "hello"

  function foo() {
    return 'hello';
  }

}

console.log(foo()); // "hello"


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с es6, функции можно объявлять внутри блоков if. В этом случае область их видимости будет заканчиваться областью if. Во избежания подобных проблем с `undefined` нужно использовать директиву `'use strict'`, тогда при обращении к необъявленной функции foo будет ошибка. Без использования этой директивы, результат будет разница в зависимости от внутренней реализации стандарта в том или ином браузере.

```
'use strict'

console.log(foo); // undefined

if(true) {

  console.log(foo()); // "hello"

  function foo() {
    return 'hello';
  }

}

console.log(foo()); // "hello"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069204/function-declarations-inside-if-else-statements